# How to make my URL to only be "localhost:8080/*"?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm just starting out with giving Spring MVC a look so I truly have no idea what I'm doing. Therefore, I started following a series of [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7i1gRv5nZY) on youtube. I've followed them step by step only differing in that I'm using STS instead of og Eclipse but I set the project up like the tut so I can't see why it would matter.

Towards the end we make an `index.jsp` page, restart the server, and navigate to `localhost:8080/index.html` and this is where my "problem" begins. I have to use `localhost:8080/test/index.html` in order to avoid a `404` error.

I think the answer is somewhat obvious but I'm not clear why mine's different than the tut's even though I followed it, names aside, exactly.

How to make my URL to only be `localhost:8080/*`? I don't want `/test/` included.

Beginning of pom.xml:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.name.spring.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>blog-aggregator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>blog-aggregator</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>     
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

IndexController.java:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp";
    }
}
```

dispatch-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="wilk.robert.spring.test.controller" />
</beans>
```

I'm guessing it has to do with my base package but that seems to limit me on what my package can be; that doesn't sound right (remember I'm ignorant!).

If there's any important code missing I will promptly add it.

Comment: which web server are u using?

Comment: I'm running it with jetty as does the tutorial. @JunedAhsan

Comment: Check my answer that should help

Comment: Just a suggestion- This has nothing to do with spring, it's more related to server specifc configuration

Comment: @Amit.rk3, thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I'm new to all this actually. First time using jetty; the tut doesn't make any config changes so I was under the false impression it would just work.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with your Jetty thing .. To me your requirement - "How to make my URL to only be localhost:8080/*? I don't want /test/ included." is more about web application configuration which means that you will need to think from web.xml perspective. so, my recommendation would be remove all existing URL patterns (html, xml, json etc.) in servlet mapping and use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` which will take care of everything .. So, when you use localhost:8080/ then your servlet named "dispatcher" will be invoked .. I am quite positive that this will help you ..

Comment: @hagrawal, thanks. I've tried many things including that. It still behaved the same way. It ended up being that the plugin xml I copied had /test as the contextPath from the example I got it from. Copy/paste is not substitute for knowledge!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your war to ROOT.war and then deploy it

> If the webapp is called root.war or the directory is called root/ then Jetty deploys it at the / context.

[jetty link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications)

Add the next line to your pom.xml to rename your war file:

```
<build>
  <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
</build>
```

If you are using the jetty plugin modify your plugin configuration like the following code:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.22</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>                     
                </configuration>
                ...
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it didn't work. Perhaps I should've mentioned I'm using the jetty plugin; does that matter?

Comment: Thanks again. I ended up realizing I needed exactly what you've provided here after looking deeper into the link you gave.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your webapp as the ROOT app. Easiest way of doing this either naming your war file as ROOT.war or taking your exploded webapp directory and rename is as ROOT

```
${jetty.home}/webapps/ROOT
```